# WM_TIMER stops suddenly in ATL ActiveX control

Tags: c++, windows, activex, atl

I originally had an ActiveX control that registered a Windows timer (with `SetTimer()`) that fires every few seconds. That worked fine so far. Now in order to implement a full screen mode, I added a child window to my control that is supposed to show the content while the control itself manages all the ActiveX stuff.

The problem that I have with this approach is that my WM_TIMER suddenly stops firing at some time. I have traced it back to `UIDeactivate()` being called on my control but I don't know why this method is called (I believe it has something to do with losing focus) when it wasn't called before.

I would also like to know why my WM_TIMER events suddenly stop while everything else still seems to work fine. And what could it have to do with showing the content in a child window instead of on the ActiveX control itself?

Comment: how is the control implemented? ATL, MFC?

Comment: It's implemented with ATL but without wizards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timers stops for a reason. Which might be:

1. You do stop timer by `KillTimer` call
2. Your window is re-created and timer is not re-enabled
3. Your control is windowless and you actually don't have a `HWND` handle
4. There is a collision in timer identifiers, there is something else (e.g. internal subclassed window) out there to use the same identifier, it sets, kill the timer and you no longer see `WM_TIMER` messages you enabled earlier
5. The window thread is busy (frozen) with some activity which does not include message dispatching, so timer itself exists, is healthy and alive, just no messages sent

The things to do - without yet additional information on the issue on hands:

1. Check threads of your window, and your Set/KillTimer calls to make sure they all make sense together
2. Use Spy++ tool to check messages posted for your window and/or in the thread of the interest, to find out if you *really* have `WM_TIMER`s missing, or they just don't reach your code; also you might see other interesting messages around

Comment: I couldn't even find the ``WM_TIMER`` messages with Spy++, even if my application's log file said so. I tried to find them in my processes and in my main threads message queue.

Comment: But I noticed something different. My message queue gets spammed with ``WM_PAINT`` messages at the time my timer stops firing. Maybe those two issues are related?

Comment: Yes they might be related. `WM_TIMER` is a low priority message, if your message queue works hardly on other messages (as opposed to your original "everything else still seems to work fine"), timer messages might be not quite on time.

Comment: I forget to validate my client area when I received the WM_PAINT message. Adding a ``ValidateRect()`` solved the missing timer issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from ATL implementation of `CComControlBase` (I would guess that your control inherits from that). Check the part marked with `<<<<<<<<<<<`:

```
inline HRESULT CComControlBase::IOleInPlaceObject_InPlaceDeactivate(void)
{
    if (!m_bInPlaceActive)
        return S_OK;

    if(m_bUIActive) {
        CComPtr<IOleInPlaceObject> pIPO;
        ControlQueryInterface(__uuidof(IOleInPlaceObject), (void**)&pIPO);
        ATLENSURE(pIPO != NULL);
        pIPO->UIDeactivate();
    }

    m_bInPlaceActive = FALSE;

    // if we have a window, tell it to go away.
    //
    if (m_hWndCD)
    {
        ATLTRACE(atlTraceControls,2,_T("Destroying Window\n"));
        if (::IsWindow(m_hWndCD))
            DestroyWindow(m_hWndCD);  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        m_hWndCD = NULL;
    }

    if (m_spInPlaceSite)
        m_spInPlaceSite->OnInPlaceDeactivate();

    return S_OK;
}
```

On deactivation, the control window gets destroyed. Therefore it can't process WM_TIMER anymore.

Comment: This ``DestroyWindow()`` is not called. The problem is, I don't even know why my control is deactivated because it hasn't been deactivated before I introduced the child window.

Comment: Even if the control is deactivated? are you sure? Which windows has the focus at that moment when you notice that WM_TIMER isn't triggered anymore?

Comment: Can you post the code which sets up the timer in your control and code which handles it?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. ``UIDeactivate()`` seems to be called only if I put another window in front of my application. But only if I use the child window. Previously it wasn't called in that situation.

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell without seeing any code, especially to which window was the timer attached and how it was handled. So far I get this: you say that DestroyWindow is not called, although you do get deactivated - this seems strange unless you have this code overridden or you have windowless control which you haven't mentioned. How is the child window created, with which styles? More or less, I can only do some guesswork

Comment: I think that ``UIDeactivate()`` and ``InPlaceDeactivate()`` are different events. The former is called in situations where my control is only hidden while the later is called when/before the control is destroyed.